# rollupjs - babelHelpers object not created

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, rollupjs

I am using rollup and babel to transpile some ES6 code and bundle the result into a single file, but I ran into some issues with babelHelpers object.

rollup.config.js:

```
export default {
  entry: './src/js/core.js',
  dest: './dist/output.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [babel({
    externalHelpers: true,
    runtimeHelpers: true,
    presets: ["es2015-rollup"]
  })],
  treeshake: false,
  useStrict: true
};
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015-rollup"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-es2015-classes",
    "external-helpers-2"
  ]
}
```

and part of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel rollup:watch lint:watch",
    "rollup": "rollup -c",
    "rollup:watch": "rollup -c -w",
    "lint": "esw rollup.config.* src/js/** --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch"
},
"dependencies": {
    "babel-helpers": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers-2": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.15.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "eslint": "^3.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-watch": "^2.1.14",
    "npm-run-all": "^3.1.2",
    "rollup": "^0.36.4",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.6.1",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "rollup-watch": "^2.5.0"
}
```

core.js:

```
var configOptions = {
  range: [0, 5],
  arg: "speak",
  options: ["listen", "mute", "speak"]
};

function updateOptions(opt) {
  if (configOptions.range == undefined) {
    configOptions.range = opt.range;
  }
}

updateOptions({});

class Hello {
  print() {
  }
}

new Hello().print();
```

bundled-output:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var configOptions = {
  range: [0, 5],
  arg: "speak",
  options: ["listen", "mute", "speak"]
};

function updateOptions(opt) {
  if (configOptions.range == undefined) {
    configOptions.range = opt.range;
  }
}

updateOptions({});

var Hello = function () {
  function Hello() {
    babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this, Hello);
  }

  babelHelpers.createClass(Hello, [{
    key: "print",
    value: function print() {}
  }]);
  return Hello;
}();

new Hello().print();

}());
```

So as you can see in core.js I'm using ES6 class. I would expect babel to only add polyfill for used objects. As currently I'm using only class I'd expect babel to use only checkClassCall and other functions for "class" feature to work. But it adds whole polyfill functionality to my final bundle.

So I did some research and found about "external-helpers-2" and options:
externalHelpers:true
runtimeHelpers:true

which packs every babel functionality inside babelHelpers but I do not know how to generate the object with all the functions at the top of my final IIFE.

**EDIT**

If i use transform-runtime then I get this in console

Treating 'babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck' as external dependency
Treating 'babel-runtime/helpers/createClass' as external dependency
No name was provided for external module 'babel-runtime/helpers/classCallCheck' in options.globa
ls – guessing '_classCallCheck'
No name was provided for external module 'babel-runtime/helpers/createClass' in options.globals
– guessing '_createClass'

also _classCallCheck and _createClass are added to my parameters in final rollup IIFE

Comment: Did you attempt to install babel-plugin-transform-runtime? It should hold the helpers you need.

Comment: I did try. The result was 2 added parameters to my IIFE _classCallCheck,_createClass but this does not solve my problem. Also this has been added _classCallCheck = 'default' in _classCallCheck ? _classCallCheck['default'] : _classCallCheck;
_createClass = 'default' in _createClass ? _createClass['default'] : _createClass; ... I do want Babel to insert classCallCheck and createClass functions at the TOP of my IIFE, not reference them as externals

Answer (score 1):

This is how I configure the babel for rollup, might work for you:

```
{
    presets        : [['es2015', {"modules": false}]], 
    runtimeHelpers : true,
    exclude        : 'node_modules/**',
    plugins        : ["external-helpers"]
}
```

if is **very** important to use `es2015` instead of `es2015-rollup`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `externalHelpers` and `runtimeHelpers` options from your Rollup.js config. `es2015-rollup` preset already contains the helpers, so just using it should be enough.

Updated Rollup.js config:

```
export default {
  entry: './src/js/core.js',
  dest: './dist/output.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [babel({
    presets: ["es2015-rollup"]
  })],
  treeshake: false,
  useStrict: true
};
```

Comment: Still does not work. Whole polyfill is included ... I only need some features